# writing pl/sql output into multiple excel worksheets in one excel

Tags: oracle, excel, plsql, plsqldeveloper

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to export the result into different tabs of Excel in Toad for Data Analyst?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135798/how-to-export-the-result-into-different-tabs-of-excel-in-toad-for-data-analyst)

I have a pl/sql code where I have two procedures in it (independent of each other) and on executing the procedure I want the output to be written in one excel file but with two worksheets in it.

Ex:
for one procedure the output should be in sheet 1

for next procedure the ouput should be in sheet 2.

can any one help?  i am using `utl_file`

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to tackle this here's some code I picked up somewhere.  Warning: for my purposes I abandoned this approach as I found that loading the XML data into Excel was too slow.  Loading a comma-separated values file is much faster although you lose the pretty formatting (not important in my case).

To use:

1. Call `WORKBOOK_OPEN` to initialize the CLOB that represents the workbook.
2. Call `WORKSHEET_OPEN` to create a worksheet in the book.
3. Use `ROW_OPEN` to create a row.
4. Make a series of calls to `CREATE_CELL` to create and populate cells in the row.
5. Continue making calls to `ROW_OPEN` and `CREATE_CELL` to create rows and cells.
6. When you're done with a worksheet call `WORKSHEET_CLOSE`.
7. If you need another worksheet call `WORKSHEET_OPEN` again to open another sheet, then use `ROW_OPEN` and `CREATE_CELL` to populate it.
8. When you're done, call `WORKBOOK_CLOSE` to close the workbook.
9. Use `EXPORT_WORKBOOK_TO_FILE` to write the workbook to a file.

Note that `EXPORT_WORKBOOK_TO_FILE` uses UTL_FILE to write its output, satisfying your requirement to use UTL_FILE.

Share and enjoy.

```
  PROCEDURE WORKBOOK_OPEN(pWorkbook  IN OUT NOCOPY CLOB) IS
  BEGIN
    pWorkbook := '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-9"?>' || chr(10) ||
                 '<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"' || chr(10) ||
                           'xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"' || chr(10) ||
                           'xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"' || chr(10) ||
                           'xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"' || chr(10) ||
                           'xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">' || chr(10) ||
                   '<ExcelWorkbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">' || chr(10) ||
                     '<WindowHeight>8580</WindowHeight>' || chr(10) ||
                     '<WindowWidth>15180</WindowWidth>' || chr(10) ||
                     '<WindowTopX>120</WindowTopX>' || chr(10) ||
                     '<WindowTopY>45</WindowTopY>' || chr(10) ||
                     '<ProtectStructure>False</ProtectStructure>' || chr(10) ||
                     '<ProtectWindows>False</ProtectWindows>' || chr(10) ||
                   '</ExcelWorkbook>' || chr(10) ||
                   '<Styles>' || chr(10) ||
                     '<Style ss:ID="Default" ss:Name="Normal">' || chr(10) ||
                       '<Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>' || chr(10) ||
                       '<Borders/>' || chr(10) ||
                       '<Font/>' || chr(10) ||
                       '<Interior/>' || chr(10) ||
                       '<NumberFormat/>' || chr(10) ||
                       '<Protection/>' || chr(10) ||
                     '</Style>' || chr(10) ||
                     '<Style ss:ID="s22">' || chr(10) ||
                       '<Font x:Family="Swiss" ss:Bold="1" ss:Underline="Single"/>' || chr(10) ||
                     '</Style>' || chr(10) ||
                   '</Styles>';
  END WORKBOOK_OPEN;  

  PROCEDURE WORKBOOK_CLOSE(pWorkbook IN OUT NOCOPY CLOB) IS
  BEGIN
    pWorkbook := pWorkbook || '</Workbook>';
  END WORKBOOK_CLOSE;

  PROCEDURE WORKSHEET_OPEN(pWorkbook          IN OUT NOCOPY CLOB,
                           pstrWorksheet_name IN            VARCHAR2) IS
  BEGIN
    --
    -- Create the  worksheet
    --
    pWorkbook := pWorkbook || '<Worksheet ss:Name="' || pstrWorksheet_name || '"><Table>';
  END WORKSHEET_OPEN;

  PROCEDURE WORKSHEET_CLOSE(pWorkbook IN OUT NOCOPY CLOB) IS
  BEGIN
    pWorkbook := pWorkbook || '</Table></Worksheet>';
  END WORKSHEET_CLOSE;

  PROCEDURE ROW_OPEN(pWorkbook IN OUT NOCOPY CLOB) IS
  BEGIN
    pWorkbook := pWorkbook || '<Row>';
  END ROW_OPEN;

  PROCEDURE ROW_CLOSE(pWorkbook IN OUT NOCOPY CLOB) IS
  BEGIN
    pWorkbook := pWorkbook || '</Row>' || chr(10);
  END row_close;

  PROCEDURE CREATE_CELL(pWorkbook          IN OUT NOCOPY CLOB,
                        pstrCell_contents  IN            VARCHAR2) IS
  BEGIN
    pWorkbook := pWorkbook || '<Cell><Data ss:Type="String"> ' ||
                  pstrCell_contents || ' </Data></Cell>';
  END CREATE_CELL;

  PROCEDURE EXPORT_WORKBOOK_TO_FILE(pstrDirectory_name IN VARCHAR2,
                                    pstrFilename       IN VARCHAR2,
                                    pWorkbook          IN CLOB)
  IS
      nChunk_size    CONSTANT BINARY_INTEGER := 32767;
      strChunk       VARCHAR2(32767);
      nPos_chr10     NUMBER;
      nWorkbook_len  NUMBER;
      fHandle        UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
      nPos           NUMBER := 1;
  BEGIN
      nWorkbook_len  := DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(pWorkbook);
      fHandle := UTL_FILE.FOPEN(pstrDirectory_name, pstrFilename, 'W', nChunk_size);

      WHILE nPos < nWorkbook_len LOOP
        strChunk := dbms_lob.substr(pWorkbook, nChunk_size, nPos);
        EXIT WHEN strChunk IS NULL;

        nPos_chr10 := INSTR(strChunk, CHR(10), -1);
        IF nPos_chr10 != 0 THEN
          strChunk := SUBSTR(strChunk, 1, nPos_chr10 - 1);
        END IF;

        UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(fHandle, strChunk, TRUE);

        nPos := nPos + LEAST(LENGTH(strChunk)+1, nChunk_size);
      END LOOP;

      UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(fHandle);
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      IF UTL_FILE.IS_OPEN(fHandle) THEN
        UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(fHandle);
      END IF;

      RAISE;   
  END EXPORT_WORKBOOK_TO_FILE;
```

Answer (score 0):

The common approach is to create the file with the [Microsoft XML Spreadsheet (XMLSS)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa140066%28v=office.10%29.aspx),  appending the content to a `VARCHAR` or `CLOB`.

For instance, to write a cell you would do something like this:

```
xmlBody := xmlBody || '<Cell><Data ss:Type="String">' || stringContent || '</Data></Cell>';
```

Now, to **open a new worksheet** you would do something like:

```
xmlBody := xmlBody || '<Worksheet ss:Name="' || yourWorksheetName || '"><Table>';
```

To close it (after appending all your content):

```
xmlBody := xmlBody || '</Table></Worksheet>';
```

There are a few utility packages that allow you to do this or you could write your own like I did. You would just have to write functions to open and close elements, for instance, openRow, closeRow, openWorkbook, closeWorkbook, openWorksheet, etc.

Refer to [Oracle PL/SQL Utility Library, codename "Alexandria"](http://code.google.com/p/plsql-utils/) for more information and examples.

Comment: But i am using utl_file..and i am confused to use xml..shall i give u code and will u edit the changes pls??....