# DB PLSQL sends out spreadsheet

Tags: excel, oracle, email, plsql

Is it possible to send out a spreadsheet with more than 1 tab from oracle DB? I am able to send out 1 tab but how would I go about adding more tabs to the spreadsheet and emailing them using oracle PLSQL?

Comment: How are you building the spreadsheet currently?  If you're generating a CSV file, for example, Excel will likely open it but there is no way to have multiple worksheets (which is what I assume you mean when you say "tab").  If you're generating an XLS/ XLSX file, whatever library you're using probably has a function to add a second worksheet.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [writing pl/sql output into multiple excel worksheets in one excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12165391/writing-pl-sql-output-into-multiple-excel-worksheets-in-one-excel)

Comment: You may also write, for example, Java code where you'll build excel file as you need and deploy it as PL/SQL [procedure](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/call-specification.html#GUID-C5F117AE-E9A2-499B-BA6A-35D072575BAD).  See [Developing Java Stored Procedures](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/jjdev/developing-Java-stored-procedures.html#GUID-AE1E5C4B-A077-4D1E-8821-6A7142BF1FEA). We've used Apache POI for such a task, but it was not about simple export, but to calculate formulas.