# toad won't recognize ORA_EXCEL as keyword

Tags: oracle, toad

I wanna try this way of exporting data but toad won't recognize ORA_EXCEL as keyword
any sugestion ??

```
BEGIN  
    ORA_EXCEL.new_document;  

    ORA_EXCEL.add_sheet('Employees');  
    ORA_EXCEL.query_to_sheet('select * from employees');  

    ORA_EXCEL.add_sheet('Departments');  
    ORA_EXCEL.query_to_sheet('select * from departments', FALSE);  

    ORA_EXCEL.add_sheet('Locations');  
    ORA_EXCEL.query_to_sheet('select * from locations');  

    -- EXPORT_DIR is an Oracle directory with at least  
    -- write permission  
    ORA_EXCEL.save_to_file('EXPORT_DIR', 'example.xlsx');  
END;
```

[enter here is the original post of this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135798/how-to-export-the-result-into-different-tabs-of-excel-in-toad-for-data-analyst)

Comment: did you install ora_excel package first of all?

Comment: This package is not a standard Oracle package.  Look [here](http://www.oraexcel.com/order)

Comment: As Egor points out, ORA_EXCEL is a third party product, so it won't be recognised by a standard template.  Oh, and it won't be called ORA_EXCEL for long: Oracle is *incredibly jealous* of its branding, and its lawyers come down on any third-party product with 'ORA' in the name.

Comment: ummm okay thank u all  i thought its free way.. anyway is there anyother free way  to do it ?? please point me to some links

Comment: I'm amazed someone's trying to sell that. There must be enough customers out there who don't bother looking at the free alternatives...

Comment: @Jeffery same same here this first time see something like that 4 sale !! anyway still need away if someone can help... thanks :)

Comment: @JeffreyKemp What are some free alternatives?

Comment: Look at XLSX_BUILDER_PKG - https://github.com/mortenbra/alexandria-plsql-utils